# Visual Studio Package won't listen to redirect instruction

Tags: .net-assembly, visual-studio-2019, vspackage

So the people who make **`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp`** had a bug in its last release (3.4.0.0).  It causes a problem when you try to generate code.  I'm able to get around the bug by dropping back to a previous release.  When I run it from a console program, it works fine.

Then I attempt to package it up (it's a code generator) into a Visual Studio Package.  Because this library is part of Visual Studio, I get the new version of this library that comes with Visual Studio (Version 16.4.2), which has this offensive bug in it.  I've tried creating an **`app.config`** with the following instructions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.4.0.0" newVersion="3.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But the package doesn't seem to honor it as I hit the same bug no matter what version of **`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp`** I have installed it in my VS package.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the bin/debug folder for your specific project? Try closing VA, do the above, then try to clean and build

Comment: Yes.  This issue is deeper than that.  The bug is baked into Visual Studio.  You can remove all the references to `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` and it still links and runs.  Visual Studio doesn't seem to care what version of this library you want, you have to take the version with the bug in it when you build a VS Package.